# Layers not loading on Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

The layers from the map I'm trying to add aren't loading. I keep getting an error message that says this:

> The layer, layer_foo, layer_bar, layer_x, cannot be added to the map.

I followed the instructions from ESRI's getting started guide. https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm But whenever I try to add layers from my organizations gallery they wont load and give me the error as stated above.

Does this have to do with my data source? I've set that to my local address [https://computer:3344] and I've set my redirect URI's to the same place.

Please advise, the headaches are strong with this one and I can't seem to find much other good documentation on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you get that error it means that the layers in your webmap are not accessible from the computer that you're currently on. You can open the URLs to the layers directly in a separate tab to double-check.

Comment: It works in another tab, but how would I go about making it available on my machine?